# Android parse Date to Insert SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I'm trying to insert a record every 30 days based on the start date and end but I can not parse ... someone help me to fix the code? Thanks

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
        String data_inizio = sdf.format( dateAndTime.getTime() );//datepicker1
        String data_fine = sdf.format( dateAndTime1.getTime() );//datepicker2

        Calendar gcal = Calendar.getInstance();
        gcal.setTime(sdf.parse( dateAndTime.getTime()));
        Calendar gcal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        gcal1.setTime(sdf.parse(data_fine));


        for(int i=0; gcal.before(gcal1); i++) {
            gcal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
                       if (gcal.before(gcal1)) {
                           // insert value into Db
...
...
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing exactly? Inserting into SQLite or date comparison before or after ?

Comment: I get the 2 dates, but I can not make a comparison to insert a record every 30 days. thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean with "can not"? Error message? Crash? Wrong result? Phone explodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code, As your requirement, I have written following method to compare two dates. This method will take a string formatted date and a duration as parameter. Duration will be add as month, day or year in string formatted date.

```
private static boolean isDateValidOrNot(String created_dateTime, int duration)
                    {
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
                        try {
                            long longNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            Date date = addDay(format.parse(created_dateTime), duration);
                            long difference = longNow - date.getTime();
                            int Hours = (int) (difference/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                            int Mins = (int) (difference/(1000*60)) % 60;
                            System.out.println("Hours : "+Hours);
                            System.out.println("Minutes : "+Mins);
                            if(Hours < 0 || Mins < 0)
                                    return true;
                            else
                                    return false;
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                return false;
        }

        public static Date addDay(Date date, int i) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
    private static Date addMonth(Date date, int i) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
    public static Date addYear(Date date, int i) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, i);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
```

Comment: sure that you have understood my problem? I need only insert a record every 30 days with a relevant date.

Comment: I am asking again, where are you facing problem , inserting a record or finding out relevant date? FYI, I have added code for add 30 days in a string formatted date, and check whether it is passed(before or after) or not.

Comment: my problem is to add 30 days to the date string received "data_inizio", so I should parse to add 30 days. please read my code to understand better.

Comment: For this I already have solution in above code, just call addDay() method 
`Date date = addDay(format.parse(created_dateTime), duration);`